# Pivot an obect in the direction of the mouse as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to have an object pivot in the direction of the mouse while being dragged.  For example i would like the car to point in the direction it is being dragged.  All I have right now is the drag and drop code.

```
car.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
car.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);



function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    }
function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you start dragging the object, you can start listening for `MouseMove` events. As you do so, you compare the current mouse position to the previous mouse position and determine the angle between the two. Then, use that angle as the `rotation` for the object:

```
car.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
car.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
var oldPoint:Point;


function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    oldPoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);

    // start listening to mouse move events
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
}
function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    oldPoint = null;
    event.target.stopDrag();

    // stop listening to mouse move events
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
}

function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(!oldPoint)
    {
        return;
    }
    var newPoint:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);

    // get the angle between the two points and set it as the rotation
    car.rotation = point_direction(oldPoint, newPoint);
}

function point_direction(p1:Point, p2:Point):Number
{
    return Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```

**NOTE:** (Per @Vesper's comment) When the mouse is going left to right, this will produce a rotation of 0. This means that you'll want the graphics of your `car` object facing towards the right.

Comment: Thanks Marcela!  There is only one problem.  When I drag the car, the side of the car is the lead point instead of the front hood.  It's probably something small but I'm new to flash.

Comment: You'll want to do one of two things: offset the rotation you get from the `point_direction` method, or re-orient the graphics of your car object so that the registration point is at the right-center. See image: http://i.gyazo.com/c2307c7113db08c92bdabff2a33eb7d0.png

Comment: Thanks Marcela! That was a big help

Comment: @Marcela You should say that the 0 rotation is facing rightwards instead of upwards, thus a better solution would be to rotate the car MC so it'll be facing rightwards in the designer.